# Calculate the expectation of a shift CDF

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is a normal random variable with mean 0, and variance $\sigma^2$.  $F(x)$ is the CDF(cumulative distribution function) of a standard normal random variable(mean 0 and variable 1), how to calculate the expectation of $ F(X+a)$, where $ a>0 $.

This was a quant interview question. I know how to calculate the expectation of F(X), i.e when $a=0$, but I have no idea when $a \neq 0$.

My solution for $a=0$:

Method 1: Since F(x) is the CDF of a normal random variable with mean 0, and variance $\sigma^2$. We will have F(x)=1-F(-x). Suppose that f(x) is the corresponding pdf, and f(x)=f(-x).  Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[F(X)]&=\int_{-\inf}^{+\inf} F(s)f(s)ds\\
&=\int_{-\inf}^{+\inf} (1-F(-s))f(s)ds\\
&=1-\int_{-\inf}^{+\inf} F(-s)f(s)ds\\
&=1-\int_{-\inf}^{+\inf} F(m)f(m)dm
\end{align}
Hence we have
$$ \int_{-\inf}^{+\inf} F(s)f(s)ds=\frac{1}{2}$$

Method 2(This method seems it didn't require that X is normal random variable): Let's first compute the distribution for $F(X)$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\{F(X) \leq y\}&=\mathbb{P}\{X \leq F^{-1}(y)\}\\
&=F\cdot F^{-1}(y)=y
\end{align}
So $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed, hence the mean is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You say that you know how to calculate $E[F(X)]$, where $F$ is the distribution function of $F$, right? What is the trick. If you show us this, then we can work on $E[F(X+a)]$.

Comment: Wait a moment. Isn't it true that $F(X)$ is uniform if $X$ has a continuous density. Therefore $E[F(X)] = 1/2$? I am not sure whether this helps us for $E[F(X+a)]$ ...

Comment: @Richard I was thinking along the same line, but as you say I'm not sure how this will help us calculate the excpecation of F(X+a). However, I think this question should be asked in math.stackexchange?

Comment: I think the question fits for both as it could really be asked in a quant interview. In my mind it is ok.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be positive drift?

Comment: @Richard, if $F(X)$ is uniform, then wouldn't $F(X+a)$ also be uniform?

Comment: @John, it definately should ... I just didn't have time for the proof. The answer must be very similar to the unshifted case.

Comment: I tried to do the calculation for the specific case ($\mu=0$) and wanted to reduce it to the unshifted one ... but I did not manage.

Comment: It's kind of 'intuitive' that it would be 1/2, but as you say @Richard, what is it you really do? I'll show what I did.. might be all wrong but maybe it will give you some ideas!

Comment: @Richard  I showed my methods for F(X).

Comment: @John & Good Guy Mike: I agree 1/2 would be a good guess, but how to prove it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This leads to the same result as Alexeys answer. However, my reasoning is different. 
$$
E[F_X(X+a)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_X(x+a) f_X(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{x+a}f_X(y)dy f_X(x)dx=\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1_{(-\infty,x+a]}(y) f_X(y) f_X(x)dydx=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 1_{_{\{y-x\le a\}}}(y) f_X(y) f_X(x)dydx.
$$

The product of the two densities in the integral is the density of a bivariate Gaussian vector (X,Y), whose components are independent and follow a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Hence this integral is the same as

$$
E[1_{\{Y-X\le a\}}]=P[\{Y-X\le a\}],
$$

where $Y,X$ are iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Thus $Y-X$ has a $N(0,2\sigma^2)$ distribution. We get

$$
E[F_X(X+a)]=F_{Y-X}(a)=\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right).
$$

Comment: Great @Andreas, thanks for sharing this proof!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is correct...

So firstly, what is $F(X)$ when $X$ is a random variabel?

This is where I might be completely wrong, but at least it gives the correct answer in the case of a=0, so let's try that one first.

We have two random variables with the same normal distribution, mean 0 and sd $\sigma^2$.
$X_1, X_2$

So we are supposed to calculate $F_{X_1}(X_2) = P(X_1 \leq X_2) = P(X_1 - X_2 \leq 0)$

Since both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both normal we have that $X =X_1 - X_2$ is also normal with mean $0$ and s.d. $2\sigma^2$

So we have $P(X \leq 0)$ which is 1/2.

For the case of $a \neq 0$ we would get $P(X \leq a)$ which is $F_{X}(a)$. However it seems like it would always end up as a constant, so the expected value seems a bit 'redundant', which makes me think that this might not be the correct solution..

edit: Also, in $P(X \leq a)$ you could divide to get, since mean is 0, divide to get standard normal and you would get $\Phi(\frac{a}{\sqrt2sigma})$ or smth like that.

edit2:

```
sigma = 2;
n = 5000000;
a=5;
mean(normcdf(normrnd(0,sigma,1,n)+a,0,sigma))
normcdf(a/(sqrt(2)*sigma),0,1)
```

Comment: It seems that you assume that $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are independent, but we need to assume they are the same random variable.

Comment: If they are the same r.v. you would end up with $P(X_1 \leq X_1) =1$? I see that you provided the correct (?) proof, interesting, I'll look into that when I get home

Comment: @GoodGuyMike Sorry to say, but this looks too complicated. Alexey's approach in the other answer is more direct (I tried something similar).

Comment: I tried simulating this in matlab, and it seems to work for $\sigma = 1$, otherwise it fails. Do you know why?

Comment: Okey, there was a minor mistake in my code, seems like it works properly now. I add the code if anyone want to look at it.

Comment: @GoodGuyMike I optimized your code a bit and it seems to work. Well done!

Comment: Hi, I like your approach, but there are problems, I think. Take the unshifted case. $P[X_1 - X_2 \le 0]$ .. but in the unshifted case $X_1 = X_2$ and therefore $X_1-X_2 = 0$. So this is true if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are different Gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and the same variance.

Comment: If $X_2 = X_1 + a$ don't you get $F_{X_1}(X_2)=P[X_1 \le X_1 + a] = 1$?

Comment: Shouldn't you analyse $P[F_{X_1}(X_2) \le x]$? and $F_{X_1}$ is a deterministic distribution function.

Comment: @Richard Actually it should be fine if you take iid copy.

Comment: @AlexeyKalmykov Yes ... but this is important. $X_1$ and $X_2$ can have the same law. but $X_1$ and $X_2 = X_1 +a$ are simply one and the same if $a = 0$.

Comment: @Richard Actually $X_1$ should be from $N(0,1)$ and $X_2$ should be from $N(0,\sigma^2)$ if I understood the problem correctly.

Comment: In the question it starts with $X \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and we want to know the expectation of $F_{X_1}(X_1 + a)$ for $a>0$ @nkhuyu is this correct? If yes, then $X_1$ and $X_2 = X_1 + a$ are far from independent.

Comment: @Richard, but that cdf equals $ P(X_1 \leq X_1 + a) = 1$

Comment: @nkhuyu are you sure they were asking for $F_X(X+a)$ instead of $F_{X+a}(X+a)$? That would require extra care in specification, instead of just saying $F(X+a)$ which should refer to the latter... One could infer from the level of other questions :-)

Comment: @Quartz $F(x)$ is the CDF of a standard normal random variable, before I didn't say this clearly. So I think I am sure it is asking $F_{X}(X+a)$, not $F_{X+a}(X+a)$

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned you can get the CDF of this distribution using distribution transform:

$$P(F(X+a)\le y)=P(F^{-1}(F(X+a))\le F^{-1}(y))=P(X+a\le F^{-1}(y))=P(X\le F^{-1}(y)-a)=F(F^{-1}(y)-a)$$

Then you could write down expectation in integral form, but on the first glance it seems not so trivial how to get an explicit expression. Probably they didn't expect you to do this.

You can also try to run quick Monte-Carlo in R to see what your distribution looks like:

```
  a <- 1
  sigma <- 2
  m <- pnorm(rnorm(10000,0,sigma)+a,0,sigma)
  hist(m)  
  plot(ecdf(m))
  mean(m)
```

You will definitely see that it's not uniform for the values of $a$ that are significantly bigger than 0.

Comment: All that I have tried ended up here too. Yes, maybe there is no (at least no easy) closed-form solution. The MC simulation persuades me ...